# A block changes its ID when moved between regions?

Tags: drupal-6, block, drupal-theming

Under Drupal 6 I have a custom block, which I have named and placed into a custom, right-hand sidebar region. This block's ID (which I have discovered from `block.tpl.php`, from the `$block_id` helper variable) is 7.

I am overriding the output of this block as it displays a View and I need to change the markup; I have a preprocess function in `template.php` called `myTheme_preprocess_block()` which searches for the block's unique ID thus:

```
myTheme_preprocess_block(&$vars) {

    $this_block_id = $vars['id']; /* region-independent ID (for reliability) */
    $vars['template_files'] = array();

    switch ($this_block_id) {

        case 7:
            $vars['template_files'][] = 'block-my-override-template';
            break;
        default:
            /* take no action */
    }
}
```

Now, I've moved this block from the right-hand sidebar region (which is a custom region and not the default one which comes with Garland) to a footer region, which also has a custom name. And suddenly, my overriding template file, `block-my-override-template.tpl.php`, is no longer referenced.

I do a little digging and output the unique block ID from within `block.tpl.php`, and magically this block has **changed** its ID from 7 to 13! With a straight face, no less! Returning this block to the right-hand sidebar region also returns the block to ID 7 (and all my code starts working again).

My question is this: How can we uniquely identify a block if its "unique" ID changes when it moves from one region to another?

Comment: Currently I'm creating a unique text tag inside the block in Drupal, e.g. `{JD_MY_BLOCKNAME}` and then, using a similar function to the above, detecting this rather than a block ID. But it seems so cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a View, why don't you instead override the block display of the View instead of mucking around with the actual block?

You could alternatively simply declare your custom block in a module? That should make it easier for you to manage theming aspects of the block.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions - I'll try these alternate methods next time. I was attempting to do the "right" thing by overriding in template.php - Drupal's general documentation is so awful I'm effectively in the deep end without a float, so to speak. ;)